# How to predict graph network given edge distance between isolated nodes and their non-adjacent node for a train system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I am trying to predict a graph network given the train.csv file in the below format using the `networkx` library in Python3.0. The train.csv file contains 250123 entries of people boarding and alighting stations and time. With the following information, i need to predict a graph network between all the stations.

I know that i am supposed to use the time difference between the `BoardingTime` and `AlightingTime` to predict the graph network.

For example for the first entry where the `BoardingStation` is **Mongkok** and `AlightingStation` is **Lai King**, the time difference between BoardingTime and AlightingTime is `14` minutes.

This timing together with all the other entries will then be used to "guess" how many stations and what are the stations between the **Mongkok** and **Lai King**. One assumption i think can be included is that the distance between two adjacent nodes is same for all nodes.

Then, we can form a big graph network prediction of nodes linkage of all the stations. For this example, the train system is the Hong Kong MTR train system so the predicted graph should look somewhat similar to the actual online Hong Kong MTR map.

The output should look like the this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx0zK.png) but with the node name as the station name and a much bigger network

```
ID      BoardingStation   BoardingTime    AlightingStation    AlightingTime
1       Mongkok           10:01:07        Lai King            10:15:13
2       Tsuen Wan         09:31:45        Mei Foo             09:44:32
3       Disneyland Resort 12:41:37        Prince Edward       13:02:18
4       Tsim Sha Tsui     12:53:30        Mongkok             13:00:09
5       Disneyland Resort 15:11:46        Kowloon Tong        15:39:48
.       ...               ...             ...                 ...
.       ...               ...             ...                 ...
.       ...               ...             ...                 ...
250123  Long Ping         10:52:55        Nam Cheong          11:08:11
```

Comment: Do not attempt to remove your question now that it has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution you can take, is to find for each station (node) all it's neighbours (connected with one edge)

you can do it easily by finding the minimum trip duration of all trips including this station either as `BoardingStation` or `AlightingStation`

once you have all the edges and nodes, construction the graph is not a problem, using `networkx` or any other lib

> this solution assumes there are trips in the db between **every** adjacent pair
>
> and also require only a fraction of the data, although you can use the other data to validate your solution by comparing expected (based on your model) trip's duration to actual

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!!